# Need help in showing decimal point for calcualtion

Tags: c++

```
#include #include #include using namespace std;

int main() { float a,b,c; cin>>a>>b>>c; float s=(float)(a+b+c)/2; float area=sqrt(s*(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)); cout<< setprecision(5) <<area; return 0; }
```

I'm writing a program for calcualting the area of a triangle highschool, the math works but the teacher wants it to schow 4 decimal positions. 
Ex: if a,b,c is equal to 3, 4 and 5 it should be 6.0000 but it only comes out as 6. 
Tried using setprecision() but it's not showing up for intergers answers. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why did you write your code as one single (and unreadable) line? Did you really copy-paste the code correctly into your question? Those `#include` tells me you didn't. So please **[edit]** your question to copy-paste the code properly.

Comment: Please post a well formatted [mre]. The posted snippet doesn't specify any included header.

Comment: Then, search about `std::fixed`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
```

add these libraries to use sqrt and setprecision function.

Comment: I don't think that this is the issue. OP seems to be implying in the question that the program compiles and runs. The only thing that OP is not happy with is the run-time behavior of the program. Therefore, I rather believe that the code posted by OP is incomplete.

Comment: Nitpicking: `iomanip` and `cmath` are _headers_ but not _libraries_. Newbies often have to learn the difference between compiling and linking and specifically how to find mistakes if the one or other fails. Hence, I would be careful about the terms even although the headers actually represent the libraries (somehow)...